# "you is" in place of "you are"

Tags: verb-agreement, descriptive-grammar

Recently I listened to this song "You is smart, you is important ..."

This is the link for this song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3H50llsHm3k

Can I say "you is" in place of "you are"?

Thanks in advance.

Best regards,

Hatem Amer

Comment: Can I sing the actual lyrics? Yes (but it's not my sort of music). Would I be down-marked in an essay for using this non-standard form? Almost certainly.

Answer (score 1):

The pronoun *you* is second person, and the verb form *is* is third person singular; this combination would be considered as non-standard (and many may call it *incorrect*).

The standard ("correct") grammatical term would be “you are” (and, accordingly, "you were").

You can say "you is" if you wish, but most would look down upon your grammar, unless you're singing that song or quoting Aibileen from *The Help*.

Answer (score -1):

always use "you are"
It is not advisable to use "you is" either in verbal or written

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. It is an expectation of Stack Exchange that answers *explain*, not merely *state*. *Why* is "you is" not advisable? Why merely "not advisable" as opposed to outright "to be avoided"? I strongly encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.